# How i can read 9 bits?

Tags: c#, byte, bit

I have the file.
I have to read every 9 bits from the file and convert it to an int value.
I know that the minimum addressable unit in memory is 8 bits, but I have a similar problem.
How can I do this?

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks, but no. This question does not give an unambiguous answer.

Comment: If the entire file is like that, a bunch of 9-bit values in a row, then it may be better to consider *reading the whole file* as one problem and not consider each 9-bit quantity individually. The overall approach for reading a file like that can be simpler and more efficient by keeping a "bit buffer" which you extract 9-bit things from and add 8-bit data to to re-fill it. Depends on the context, so what is the context? E: also for an actual concrete answer, the specific way in which the 9-bit things are packed together matters.

Comment: And the "duplicate" is just really bad. The answers there are bad even for *that* question, and worse for this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read 2 bytes. Take all of the bits of the first byte and store them in an int (let's call it `firstbyte`). Take just the 1st bit of the second byte (which is just a 1 or a 0; let's call it `extrabit`). This must be appended to the end of the first byte (which needs to be shifted left by 1 to make room).

The output you need is then:

```c
output = (firstbyte << 1) + extrabit;
```

**Edit because I hadn't read the question properly**: the boundaries line up every 8*9 = 72 bits. In a loop, you can read 9 bytes into an array `input`, and just create 8 9-bit ints from them (in an array `output`).

You basically do it by generalizing the code I gave above to any array of input and output, like so:

```c
/* in a loop */
// read 9 bytes into an array called input
// initialize an array output[8]
for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
    output[i] = (input[i] << i + 1) + (input[i + 1] && (1 << (i + 1) - 1));
}
```

Note that the `&& ~(1 << (7 - i) - 1)` is a bit mask which selects the most significant i + 1 bits.

Comment: Yes and how would you read the next 9 bits.....?

Comment: @AndreiMiculiță Thank you very much for the answer, but how do I do this if I need to read all bytes of the file in this way?

Comment: Read a long and a byte (9bytes), then you have 8 whatevers worth of info. For the first 7 whatevers you just need to shift/mask the long around to knock bits off the left and right. For the final 9 bytes you shift the long left 9 and | the byte

Comment: (Or just look to see if the long is odd to know whether to set bit 9 of the byte (promote it to int))